# How to render in TYPO3 (vhs+flux extension) only a part of a content?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I wrote my own extension using flux+vhs+builder(TYPO3 LTS 8.7.24). Everything works fine. Now, when the user creates a content, I want to output it to two places on a page. At one place only the image should be printed and at the other place the image and the text.

EDIT-This part was a wrong approach,  an example what I need and a new approach:

[This is how my backend looks atm.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Yd9.png)

[This is how my frontend looks atm.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDYE5.png)

Now when the User put in a product Info (in "Product configuration"), he also have to put the image in the backend (in "Choose a product"). This would be double work ("Choose a product" has the same img like "Product configuration" just with some javascript). I am searching for a solution to render (a part of) the column1 also in the "Product choose" section, so I dont need column0 not anymore.

EDIT---- My last approach was also wrong. But now I got a solution with some bugs to fix. I will try to use it. If some one had the same problems, I used glue! like:

```
        <f:for each="{content}" as="meineproduct">
            <v:iterator.explode content="{meineproduct}" as="current" glue="<!---->">
                {current.1}
            </v:iterator.explode>
        </f:for>
    </v:content.render>
```

The only Problem was that it was nested. Because it took the TYPO3 class beginnings. Now I added more "" and grab the second array. Special Thanks to @Claus Due

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be thinking about this the wrong way. If your intention is to render a list of certain content elements as an index (jumping to anchor links) then you shouldn't be creating two instances of the same content element.

Rather, you should enable the "Section index" behavior toggle in the content element you want to include in such lists, then create an instance of the "Menu" content element and select a "section index" as menu type.

This content type then renders a special menu of all content elements (regardless of type) which have been selected to be shown in a section index. It is highly recommended to use the built-in way to include a content element as section index - if that is indeed your use case.

Alternative approaches using non-standard methods / for custom use cases not similar to section index:

1. Use a Fluid condition on `colPos` from the content record to determine how to render the element.
2. Use content element settings / Flux form settings to define a "display mode" for your content element that changes how it renders.
3. Combine `v:variable.register.set` and `v:variable.register.get` to define and read variables from within Fluid, that will persist across any boundary between content elements. Use `.set` in the page template where you want to output in a special way, then `.get` it in the content element template and use `f:if` to render different sections based on the value (or no value) of the variable you set with `v:variable.register.set`.

Comment: Hey @Claus Due, Thank you so much for ur qanswer. I coulndt work on it cause I destroyed my TYPO3 so have to fix it first. 
Now I understand the parameter index. TY! It was a real wrong way. 

My explaination was wrong. I want just always give out the same Column <v:content.render column="0" /> like:

<div class="one"> render column0 "part1"</div>
<div class="two"> render column0 "part2"</div>

Comment: Feel free to update the question and ping me with a comment here, perhaps I can give better recommendations if you give a more precise use case!

Comment: I edited the Question! Even if you dont have a solution, thank you so much for the offer!

Comment: Normally you should be creating proper "Product" model records and TCA for this, then use those in your templates and render them in different ways. Using content elements is a shortcut: it's easy, but forces you to use bad or hard-to-maintain solutions. I've added a third option to my list above that should work for your use case - but isn't recommended as go-to strategy. Best choice: models for your products, content element to show one or more selected products.

Comment: Ty again for ur answer. At the end of the day I used: <v:content.render column="0" as="content">

   <f:for each="{content}" as="meineproduct">
    <v:iterator.explode content="{meineproduct}" as="current" glue="<!---->">
     {current.1}
    </v:iterator.explode>
   </f:for>
  </v:content.render>

There are some bugs, like nested rendering :D But I hope I can solve this issue too. If You have a hint it would be cool :)